# First letter to be uppercase and if Name line is empty print out "can't be empty"

Tags: java, uppercase

System.out.println("Ange följande:");

```
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    String firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
    firstName = firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + firstName.substring(1).toLowerCase();

    while (firstName.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Name line can't be empty!!");
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: You did not say what the problem is here.

Comment: probably the indexoutofbounds

Comment: Please describe your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    String firstName = keyboard.nextLine();

    while (firstName.trim().equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Name line can't be empty!!");
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
    firstName = firstName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + firstName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(firstName);
```

move the line where you make the first letter upper case after the while and also use `trim()` in your while statement to make sure there are not just space entered

Comment: Thanks! Works just perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can put any string instead of Abcd in the below code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String check = "Abcd";
    if(check.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("can't be empty...");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    char charAt = check.charAt(0);
    if(Character.isUpperCase(charAt)){
        //do stuff condition satisfied
    }
}
```